# How to duplicate paging buttons on a SharePoint blog to avoid long scrolling?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, blog, paging, 2016

Since the paging buttons of a SharePoint blog are at the bottom of the page, users have to scroll down all the posts displayed if they want to see older posts.

How can I duplicate paging buttons to the top of the page so users can access it without having to scroll down ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a little script using JQuery to duplicate paging buttons to a more convenient place. 
I tested it on SharePoint 2013, 2016 (ITPreview), Online (working at the time I write this answer).

1- About the blog site, disable "Minimal Download Strategy" feature from site feature management screen

2- Edit the top page of the blog and add a "script editor" webpart

3- Copy the following script into the newly added webpart and save the page

```
<script>


function CopyPaging()
{
    // Cloning pager
    var $cloned = $("[id^='scriptPagingWPQ']").clone();

    // Replacing all html id attributes and setting a few css properties to center the new pager
    $cloned.prop('id', 'newScriptPaging' );
    $cloned.find(".ms-bottompaging").prop('id', 'newBottomPaging').css("text-align", "center").css("width", "100%");
    $cloned.find(".ms-bottompaging>div").prop('id', 'newGUID');
    $cloned.find("[id^='bottomPagingCell']").prop('id', 'newBottomPagingCell');
    $cloned.find("[id$='prev']").prop('id', 'newPrev' );
    $cloned.find("[id$='next']").prop('id', 'newNext' );

    // Adding new pager to the page (at the bottom of the column on the right side)
    // You may want to choose another location
    $(".ms-blog-LeftColumn").append($cloned);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', CopyPaging);
});

</script>
```

**Be Careful, you need to include JQuery for the script to execute** (you can for instance include it into your masterpage or at the top within the script editor part)

Step by step guide here:
http://sprecipe.com/2015/12/30/pimp-my-sharepoint-episode-2-duplicate-paging-buttons-to-avoid-long-scrolling-on-sharepoint-blogs/